# Jquery Mobile для переходов между страницами

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Подскажите, пожалуйста, такую вещь. Делаю сайт портфолио и хочу сделать какие-то нестандартные переходы между страницами. Наткнулся на jquerymobile.com. Там есть такая история как `page-transition`. Но я только знакомлюсь с JS и его фрэймворками и не могу сообразить - можно ли такие переходы делать между несколькими html страницами. У меня получилось сделать такой переход только вперед и назад. Дальше переход не работает, выдает ошибку. Можно ли сделать `page-transition` между скажем 10-ью разными страницами? Куда копать?

Comment: Покажите код, который работает и который не работает.

Comment: Могу показать сайт: http://72-dpi.ru/
Делаю как тут описано: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html
Но переход срабатывает только вперед и назад. Чтоб после перехода, со второй страницы перейти на 3-ю, надо перегрузить страницу. Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 2):

В консоль заглядывали? *GET http://72-dpi.ru/index/index/stone-magazine2.html 404 (Not Found)*

Исправить можно так (поставив слэш перед index в href):

```
<a href="/index/stone-magazine5.html" class="ar-right ui-link" data-transition="slide"><span>Stone Magazine</span></a>
```

Плюс *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }* в коде (лишние закрывающие скобки):

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
});

});
```